# Autopilot and java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, air-native-extension

I'm trying to create Adobe Air native extension for Angroid using UrbanAirship library urbanairship-lib-4.0.4.jar.

All is working fine untill I move options assigment (AppKey, AppSecret, etc.) from main application class into autopilot class. According to http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/Autopilot.html autopilot postpones takeOff and this is exactly what I need to call takeOff after native extension was initialized and set all needed options for UrbanAirship. All is working OK but I have to wait longer for first PN (I guess that's the consiquence of using autopilot). Problem starts when app is wiped from recent apps screen (not running in background) and then PN comes:

```
08-21 19:20:16.019: I/GCM(15483): GCM message air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications 0:1408620017436060%0#b0e5f2beea92a435
08-21 19:20:16.039: I/ActivityManager(594): Start proc air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications for broadcast air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications/com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: pid=5483 uid=10138 gids={50138, 3003}
08-21 19:20:16.089: I/MyAutoPilot(5483): Settings initialization
08-21 19:20:16.209: D/AndroidRuntime(5483): Shutting down VM
08-21 19:20:16.209: W/dalvikvm(5483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41588ba8)
08-21 19:20:16.209: W/GCM-DMM(15483): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications (has extras) }
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): Process: air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications, PID: 5483
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2426)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MyAutoPilot.execute(MyAutoPilot.java:47)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.urbanairship.Autopilot.automaticTakeOff(Autopilot.java:110)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver.onReceive(GCMPushReceiver.java:53)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2419)
08-21 19:20:16.209: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     ... 10 more
```

and then....

```
08-21 19:20:24.608: I/ActivityManager(594): Process air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications (pid 5483) has died.
08-21 19:21:06.092: I/ActivityManager(594): Start proc air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications for service air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications/com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService: pid=5536 uid=10138 gids={50138, 3003}
08-21 19:21:06.172: I/MyAutoPilot(5536): Settings initialization
08-21 19:21:06.282: D/AndroidRuntime(5536): Shutting down VM
08-21 19:21:06.282: W/dalvikvm(5536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41588ba8)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536): Process: air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications, PID: 5536
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2582)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at tv.mhub.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MyAutoPilot.execute(MyAutoPilot.java:47)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at com.urbanairship.Autopilot.automaticTakeOff(Autopilot.java:110)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService.onCreate(EventService.java:94)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
08-21 19:21:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(5536):     ... 10 more
```

ApplicationManifest includes:

```
<application android:enabled="true">
<meta-data android:name="com.urbanairship.autopilot" android:value="xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MyAutoPilot" />           



<!-- Needed for Action.startActivityForResult -->
<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity"/>



<!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED
- Set or Remove the parent activity
- For more customization details, see com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity -->
<activity
       android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
       android:parentActivityName="xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MainActivity"
       android:exported="false">

      <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MainActivity" />

      <intent-filter>
           <action ndroid:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION"/>
           <data android:scheme="http" />
           <data android:scheme="https" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
</activity>



<!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship GCM-->
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />
<receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"   
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
            <category android:name="air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!--  REQUIRED for detecting when the application is upgraded so it can request a new GCM ID -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>



<service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service"/>
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service"/>
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />



<!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
<!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.push.sample" with your package name -->
<provider android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"

 android:authorities="air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications.urbanairship.provider"

 android:permission="air.xx.xxxx.testPushNotifications.permission.UA_DATA"
                                      android:exported="true"
                                      android:multiprocess="true" />
 <!-- END OF REQUIRED ITEMS -->


 <!-- OPTIONAL (for segments support) -->
 <service android:name="com.urbanairship.location.LocationService" android:label="Segments Service"/>

 <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
 <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
 <receiver android:name="xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.IntentReceiver" />

</application>
```

Application class:

```
package xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.urbanairship.analytics.InstrumentedActivity;

public class MainActivity extends InstrumentedActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

Autopilot:

```
package xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions;
import com.urbanairship.Autopilot;
import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;

public class MyAutoPilot extends Autopilot {

    private static final String TAG = "MyAutoPilot";

    private String _appKey;
    private String _appSecret;
    private String _gcmSender;
    private Boolean _inProduction;

    public void setAppKey(String appKey){
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting appKey");
        _appKey = appKey;
    }

    public void setAppSecret(String appSecret){
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting appSecret");
        _appSecret = appSecret;
    }

    public void setGcmSender(String gcmSender){
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting gcmSender");
        _gcmSender = gcmSender;
    }

    public void setInProduction(Boolean inProduction){
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting inProduction");
        _inProduction = inProduction;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Application application) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Settings initialization");

        AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(application);

        if(_inProduction) {
            options.productionAppKey = _appKey;
            options.productionAppSecret = _appSecret;
        }
        else {
            options.developmentAppKey = _appKey;
            options.developmentAppSecret = _appSecret;
        }

        options.inProduction = _inProduction;
        options.transport = "gcm";
        options.gcmSender = _gcmSender;

        UAirship.takeOff(application, options);

        PushManager.enablePush();

        PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
    }

}
```

FREFunction:

```
package xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.functions;

import xx.xxxx.PushNotificationsUrbanAirship.MyAutoPilot;
import android.util.Log;

import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREInvalidObjectException;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;
import com.adobe.fre.FRETypeMismatchException;
import com.adobe.fre.FREWrongThreadException;

public class RegisterWithUAFunction implements FREFunction {

    private static final String TAG = "RegisterWithUAFunction";

    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            MyAutoPilot autoPilot = new MyAutoPilot();
            autoPilot.setAppKey(args[0].getAsString());
            autoPilot.setAppSecret(args[1].getAsString());
            autoPilot.setGcmSender(args[2].getAsString());
            autoPilot.setInProduction(args[3].getAsBool());

            Log.i(TAG, "About to execute takeOff");

            autoPilot.execute(context.getActivity().getApplication());
        }
        catch(FREInvalidObjectException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(FRETypeMismatchException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(FREWrongThreadException e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

IntentReceiver is exactly like in [example](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples/tree/master/PushSample)

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Hi everyone, finally I managed to solve this problem. Main problem was that sometimes AutoPilot can start before Adobe Air Native Extension. In such case appKey and appSecret will be equal to null. To solve this issue I was suggested to use SharedPreferences to store all relevant keys. More details here: https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples/issues/14